# add language parameter to link with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, routes

this is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^login(.*)$ index.php?tab1=login [QSA,L]
```

this make this url

(localhost/example/login)

and in php $_GET['tab1'] its return login >> it works fine

but I want to make this urls

(localhost/example/login)

(localhost/example/en/login)

(localhost/example/fr/login)

with $_GET['lang'] to return the language in url

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ index.php?tab1=$3&lang=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: i am  tried it many times and tried the edit 
it give me not found url 
http://localhost/here/login
http://localhost/here/fr/login
http://localhost/here/en/login

Comment: In which directory you are using the rule!

Comment: i want to make it like this
https://www.jobzella.com/login
https://www.jobzella.com/en/login
https://www.jobzella.com/ar/login
but in my case i want it in localhost for development

Comment: Okay even though where are you using the rule in root directory or example is a directory?

Comment: i don`t understand what you mean with 'directory you are using the rule'
this is my code in httacess and index.php
https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-NUGcg_7VnY8/WJ7XslyxkRI/AAAAAAAACqw/crKHcRDNBtw6LGPrpUoXqZ-We_C-k3Q1ACLcB/s1600/geww.PNG

https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-IkznE_EMAJM/WJ7XsqjwaRI/AAAAAAAACq0/49TacUXTqVQ2_f-mGBO2yj5l0Txo65xjACLcB/s1600/efww.PNG

Comment: I mean in which directory your htaccess file is stored how are you checking the rules?

Comment: this is my code in httacess and index.php
https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-NUGcg_7VnY8/WJ7XslyxkRI/AAAAAAAACqw/crKHcRDNBtw6LGPrpUoXqZ-We_C-k3Q1ACLcB/s1600/geww.PNG

https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-IkznE_EMAJM/WJ7XsqjwaRI/AAAAAAAACq0/49TacUXTqVQ2_f-mGBO2yj5l0Txo65xjACLcB/s1600/efww.PNG

Comment: Your index.php file is also stored here `C:\AppServ\www\here`?